# Is it wise to use a Generalized Linear Model (GLM) to investigate trends in abundance over time?

Tags: r, time-series, generalized-linear-model, count-data

Not sure if this would be considered as being a "stupid" question, but I am still very new to statistical analyses. I have population abundance data and I wish to determine whether the trend in abundance (abundance values = counts) over time (time=years) shows an increasing/declining trend. Should (or rather, can) I make use of a GLM to investigate the trend in abundance over time (ie dependent variable = abundance value, independent variable=year (ie time)) ? Or is there perhaps a "better" alternative?

Thanks again :)

Comment: Abundance seems like a construct. Are you sure it's well defined in your dataset? A GLM has no nuance or subtlety. If, for instance, you have gross output from, say, an apple farm, and the quantity sold to local grocers, and you define abundance to be the difference of those two quantities, someone may take issue with the construct - that wouldn't inform the choice of model at all, of course.

Answer (score 1):

GLMs are a very large class of models, even for general count data so that, by using a GLM, there are likely a few ways to "do it right" and to "do it wrong". Certainly, if you Google "GLM for count data" you'll likely be pointed to Poisson regression, which is a classic and well understood type of model. A simple trend test can be constructed by fitting exactly the model described by @Allan.

$$ \log(E[\text{Count} | \text{Year} ]) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \text{Year}$$

Where year is continuously coded. The interpretation of $\exp(\beta_0)$ would be the expected Count at Year 0 (if you're starting at, say, 2000, best to center the variable at this value so that Year=1 corresponds to 2001 and so forth). $\exp(\beta_1)$ is then the average proportional increase in Count each subsequent year. So a value of 1 indicates no change at all, and a value of 1.1 indicates a 10% increase year-to-year. This is exactly the inference you will find in the standard model output. Is the trend parameter $\beta_1$ different from 0?

A probabilistically interesting trait about Poisson models is that the variance is exactly equal to the mean. Because of this, few observations with very large counts can lead to overly precise inference. A remedy with surprisingly implications in small sample sizes - specifically a small number of rows - is the use a *quasi*poisson model. In this case, we allow the variance to be *proportional* to the mean through a dispersion parameter. Unlike a parametric Poisson regression, the semiparametric quasipoisson method is not invariant to disaggregation. This means the number of rows in the dataset tell us something about our precision, which in many cases is an appropriate safeguard to overly precise inference.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Generalized Additive Models (GAM) with a poisson distribution to model this. GAMs are very flexible, allowing you to model both linear and nonlinear effects for predictors. There are lots of good tools, blogs, and books out there. Specifically, look up the `mgcv` package (by Simon Wood) and the `gratia` package (by Gavin Simpson). The `mgcv` package provides an extensive set of tools for building GAM models and the `gratia` package will allow you to detect significant change points using the finite difference method with the `derivatives()` function.

The best intro I've found would be Simon Wood's book Generalized Additive Models An Introduction with R.

Some free courses are around the web too [here is one](https://noamross.github.io/gams-in-r-course/) and [another by Gavin Simpson](https://github.com/gavinsimpson/physalia-gam-course).

There are a ton of blogs out there too to get you started. Gavin Simpson has a blog where he goes into a lot of details about fitting time series data with GAMs and detecting change points etc [here](https://fromthebottomoftheheap.net/).

Here is a [list](https://github.com/noamross/gam-resources) of additional resources that has been compiled.

Good luck!

Comment: This isn't an answer to the specific question. With the very little detail about the dataset and analysis, can you really explain why the GAM would be better than a GLM - and why a GLM would be the *wrong* choice?

Comment: @AdamO I never said that a GLM would be wrong. I did actually mean to post it to his other question https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/584060/model-test-to-determine-whether-a-trend-in-abundance-over-time-is-significant but accidentally clicked this one without realizing till just now. However, GAMs would work and may work better if there are nonlinear effect as I've found to be common with such data. If there are only linear effects it will be a glm. GAMs will also be more useful when he inevitably adds additional predictor variables (since year doesn't actually drive any processes).

Comment: Hmm.. what might you mean by a non-linear effect? In my post, I suggest modeling the log transformed mean. But if you mean that the empirical time series doesn't show a constant increase over time, then should we really be surprised? The point of a model is precisely that: to *model*. In this case, the choice of time as a covariate is pragmatic - the "trend"   is best understood as a continuous increase. I agree we could consider generalization of the single-covariate trend test by incorporating other predictors, but how exactly will a GAM do that whereas a GLM won't?

Answer (score -3):

I don't know your specific problem, but seem that you can make a model in this fashion:
$$counts = time \beta$$
So if there is significance in your model you can analyze the signal of beta and another stuff.

Comment: I think the reason this is accumulating downvotes is that it is very short, and does not explain why this is a good solution to to OP's question.